# How to remove members of a list in python

Tags: python, set

I have the following code to remove from the `data` list all sublists for which `nums` is a subset.and I dont understand why its not working:

```
data=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
nums=[1,2]

for each in data:
    if set(nums).issubset(each):
        data.remove(each)

print(data)
>>[[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Why isn't [1,2,4] being removed when nums is a subset of it, as seen below?

```
set(nums).issubset([1,2,4])
>>True
```

Comment: you just remove the first occurrence. Please fix the indentation for line containing `data.remove...`

Comment: Removing from a list while iterating through it doesn't work well. Better to just use listcomp. [i for i in data nums.issubset(i)]

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks I've fixed that, was a typo. Still behaves the same way though

Comment: try `[i for i in data if not set(nums).issubset(i)]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're modifing the list you're iterating from.

This is a nicer solution:

```
data=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
nums=[1,2]

data = [each for each in data if not set(nums).issubset(each)]
print(data)
```

For learning purposes, see this code which also works. The difference with your code is that here we're not modifying `data` list in the `for` loop.

```
data=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
nums=[1,2]

new_data = []
for each in data:
    if not set(nums).issubset(each):
        new_data.append(each)

data = new_data
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the iterator is unaware that you removed an element. When it passes to the second element, it finds `[1, 3, 4]` meaning that you skipped `[1, 2, 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

For your information, there is also a `filterfalse` function in the very useful [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) module.

```
from itertools import filterfalse

data = list(filterfalse(set(nums).issubset, data))
```